# Micrometer - only some metrics are showing up in Prometheus

Tags: java, prometheus, micrometer

Our application uses a wrapper method to execute endpoints, where each endpoint has its own custom tag. Our wrapper looks like this:

```
public static <T> T meterEndpoint(MeterRegistry meterRegistry, Tags tags, Supplier<T> t) {
        return meterRegistry.timer(Metrics.EXEC_TIME, tags).record(() -> {
            try {
                T response = t.get();
                meterRegistry.counter(Metrics.SUCCESSFUL_REQUEST, tags).increment();
                return response;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.error("Failed executing request with tags {}", tags, ex);
                tags.and("errorName", ex.getClass().getSimpleName());
                meterRegistry.counter(Metrics.FAILURE_REQUEST, tags).increment();
                throw ex;
            }
        });
    }
```

So the endpoints would call the wrapper like:

```
public String create(@RequestBody String message, @PathVariable String customer){
        Tags tags = Tags.of("endpoint", "create").and("customer", customer);
        return meterEndpoint(meterRegistry, tags, () -> dummyService.create(message));
    }

public String update(@RequestBody String message, @PathVariable String customer){
        Tags tags = Tags.of("endpoint", "update").and("customer", customer);
        return meterEndpoint(meterRegistry, tags, () -> dummyService.update(message));
    }
```

When I debug and check the value of the EXEC_TIME timer, I get an actual value for the measure. But nothing is showing up in Prometheus.
And for the counter, only metrics for some endpoints are appearing, but not others.

Comment: And what is show on your metrics page?

Comment: @markalex You mean at actuator/metrics? When I start up my application locally, I only get the default metrics. But if I call an endpoint such as create, then I see the SUCCESS_REQUEST or FAILURE_REQUEST metrics

Comment: Also, running the app locally and going to /actuator/prometheus shows the expected metrics

Comment: If you metrics page is seen by prometheus, all it's values are scraped, unless they are dropped by relabel config. Investigate relabeling setup in your instance of prometheus.